# how to make openCV solvepnp head pose estimation output more accurate

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV solvepnp to do real-time head pose estimation (x,y,z, pitch, yaw, roll) I am using that information to show the user the correct view in the video game so if he rolls his head the same thing will happen in the video game (like Xbox Kinect ).
The problem is that even when the user's head is constant the output am getting is noisy (showing the user moving his head when it's not ) or when he is moving  his head the output is not smooth and the coordinates are jumping all over the place.
I tried adding more 2d points (facial landmark) and different flags for solvepnp and even solvepnpransac but nothing worked.
here is the code i am using

```
double getCordinates(double *listPtr, int size, int imCols, int imRows, int position)
{

    // 2D image points.
    std::vector<cv::Point2d> image_points;
    // Nose tip
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2d(*(listPtr + 0), *(listPtr + 1)));
    // Chin
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2d(*(listPtr + 2), *(listPtr + 3)));
    // Left eye left corner
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2d(*(listPtr + 4), *(listPtr + 5)));
    // Right eye right corner
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2d(*(listPtr + 6), *(listPtr + 7)));
    // Left Mouth corner
     image_points.push_back(cv::Point2d(*(listPtr + 8), *(listPtr + 9)));
    // Right mouth corner
     image_points.push_back(cv::Point2d(*(listPtr + 10), *(listPtr + 11)));


    // 3D model points.
    std::vector<cv::Point3d> model_points;
    // Nose tip
    model_points.push_back(cv::Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    // Chin
    model_points.push_back(cv::Point3d(0.0, -330.0, -65.0));
    // Left eye
    model_points.push_back(cv::Point3d(-225.0, 170.0, -135.0));
    // Right eye
    model_points.push_back(cv::Point3d(225.0, 170.0, -135.0));
    // Left Mouth
    model_points.push_back(cv::Point3d(-150.0, -150.0, -125.0));
    // Right mouth
    model_points.push_back(cv::Point3d(150.0, -150.0, -125.0));
 

    // Camera internals
    double focal_length = imCols;
    // Approximate focal length.
    cv::Point2d center = cv::Point2d(imCols / 2, imRows / 2);
    cv::Mat camera_matrix = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << focal_length, 0, center.x, 0, focal_length, center.y, 0, 0, 1);
    // Assuming no lens distortion
    cv::Mat dist_coeffs = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
    // Output rotation and translation
    cv::Mat rotation_vector;
    // Rotation in axis-angle form
    cv::Mat translation_vector;
    // Solve for pose
    cv::solvePnP(model_points, image_points, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, rotation_vector, translation_vector, false,0);


    // convert rotation vector to retotation matrix

    cv::Mat rotation_matrix;
    cv::Rodrigues(rotation_vector, rotation_matrix);
    // get eulerAngles
    cv::Vec3d eulerAngles;
    cv::Mat cameraMatrix, rotMatrix, transVect, rotMatrixX, rotMatrixY, rotMatrixZ;
    double *_r = rotation_matrix.ptr<double>();
    double projMatrix[12] = {_r[0], _r[1], _r[2], 0,
                             _r[3], _r[4], _r[5], 0,
                             _r[6], _r[7], _r[8], 1};

    cv::decomposeProjectionMatrix(cv::Mat(3, 4, CV_64FC1, projMatrix),
                                  cameraMatrix,
                                  rotMatrix,
                                  transVect,
                                  rotMatrixX,
                                  rotMatrixY,
                                  rotMatrixZ,
                                  eulerAngles);

    double xTurn = eulerAngles[0];
    double yTurn = eulerAngles[1];
    double zTurn = eulerAngles[2];

    if (position == 1)
        return translation_vector.ptr<double>()[0];
    else if (position == 2)
        return translation_vector.ptr<double>()[1];
    else if (position == 3)
        return translation_vector.ptr<double>()[2];
    else if (position == 4)
        return xTurn;
    else if (position == 5)
        return yTurn;
    else if (position == 6)
        return zTurn;

    return xTurn;
}
```

Comment: A general C++ programming advice (will not help with this particular problem but will improve your code quality): Using a double-pointer (double *) as a pointer to a list is considered as bad practice. Use std::vector<double> instead. It works exactly like your std::vector<cv::Point3d>.

Comment: alright got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your measurements of the heads position is noisy. One (and propably the best) solution to deal with your noisy measurements is a Kalman Filter. The result for the 2 dimensional case without pitch, yaw and roll then looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Z_8-Ew7u2k.

As you can see in the video, the kalman filter (blue/red line) does not directly follow the noisy measurements (green dots) but instead 'as you want'.

However, designing a kalman filter is not trivial. At first, you should deal with a simpler problem to learn how kalman filtering works and then go back to your original problem. Unfortunately, that is all what I can do for you.

### Edit

I just found an interessting paper about 3-dimensional head tracking without pitch, yaw and roll. [Head Pose Estimation Based on Head Tracking and the Kalman Filter](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1875389211007206) . You will find there the matrices required for the kalman filter.

I think that there should be a directly working solution for exactly your problem somewhere. But unfortunately, I must admit that I'm unable to find it, sorry.

Comment: thank you for your answer,I'll start researching how to design a kalman filter.

Comment: There is a tutorial explaining how a ball can be tracked using OpenCV and a kalman filter https://www.myzhar.com/blog/tutorials/tutorial-opencv-ball-tracker-using-kalman-filter/. Maybe it is not the best tutorial but the video is interesting to watch.

Comment: in addition you can use Lucas-Kanade optical flow as prediction step in Kalman filter